# Animation Nodes: Ability to create mesh and assign UV coordinates?

Tags: animation-nodes

So far, working on the 1.0/master branch of Animation Nodes, I've been having a rather hard time creating procedural mesh data, and I eventually ended up just writing a python script to create the data that I wanted output - but I've just come to a barrier that would actually prohibit my next phase of the design I'm currently working on: I want to assign procedural UV coordinates to the procedural mesh that I've just created. My script currently outputs (VectorList, PolygonIndicesList) data for a Mesh Data node, and I am assigning that MeshData to an Object in the scene. I think that it is here where I seem to be lacking the options for UV data...?

I guess this question is two part:

1. Is there currently an efficient workflow for generating procedural meshes in Animation Nodes?
2. Is there any way to create procedural UV coordinates for that same mesh?

I was also having a hard time finding documentation or examples of the above, so if there are any currently available resources on this topic, I would really appreciate some links covering the topic.

Thanks! :D

Comment: While animation nodes focus on animating data, [sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) has it's main focus on generating mesh data. The uv data can be found in `obj.data.uv_layers['UVMap'].data[x].uv` - there is one `data[x].uv` for each face vertex, but I'm not sure on the relationship between each face and the uv data, I only guess `polygon[0].vertex[0] == data[0].uv` and `polygon[0].vertex[1] == data[1].uv`...